# SwiftUI State vars not updating inside TextField onSubmit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have the following code in my SwiftUI view:

```
 @EnvironmentObject var settings:Settings

 @State var presetname:String = ""

 @State var presets:[RecordingPreset] = []
 @State var currentPreset = RecordingPreset()
```

And then in the `body` var:

```
   Section("Rename") {
            TextField(currentPreset.name!, text: $presetname)
                .onSubmit {
                    settings.renamePreset(presetname, preset: currentPreset)
            
                    presets = settings.presets //<-- This is not updated
                    currentPreset = settings.currentPreset //<-- This is also not updated
                    
                   NSLog("Updating current preset name to \(currentPreset.name),
                        \(settings.currentPreset.name)")
                 //The two names above are not same until I dismiss and reopen the app, why?
                }
        }
```

As seen in code comments above, I can see through `NSLog` that the State vars `presets` and `currentPreset.name` not getting updated, why is it so? I can share more code if anyone needs.

EDIT: The problem I find is that `RecordingPreset` is a struct that confirms to `Equatable`, `Identifiable`

```
 public struct RecordingPreset:Equatable, Identifiable {

    public static func == (lhs: RecordingPreset, rhs: RecordingPreset) -> Bool {
      return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    public var id:UUID

    public var name:String?
    ...
 }
```

It seems SwiftUI refuses to update the State vars because the `id` of all elements in the array stay same even though member `name` is changed. As a workaround, I am forced to do the following:

```
  Section("Rename") {
            TextField(currentPreset.name!, text: $presetname)
                .onSubmit {
                    settings.renamePreset(presetname, preset: currentPreset)
            
                    presets = [] //Force update
                    presets = settings.presets
                    currentPreset = settings.currentPreset
                }
        }
```

Comment: Did you do an async task on `renamePreset` method?

Comment: No, not any async task. Just updation of Userdefaults.

Comment: This is just how `@State` and a few other SwiftUI property wrappers work. Their setters will not immediately change what their getters return, so the change is not visible through an `NSLog` immediately after calling the setter. Do you have an *actual, practical* problem here? If so, please show a [mcve], something I can directly copy and paste into my IDE and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Side note: you seem to have two sources of truth here - `presets` and `settings.presets`. What's the point of `presets` when you can do `settings.presets`, or `$settings.presets` for the binding? The same goes for `currentPreset` vs `settings.currentPreset`.

Comment: @Sweeper My legacy settings class is a mess. It has two possible sources of truth -- UserDefaults OR a user supplied settings dictionary from which to fetch settings values. It therefore uses lot of computed properties. As a result, I had to manually make it observable by calling `objectWillChange.send()` at different places.

Comment: @Sweeper Most of my settings are computed properties so I can not use bindings.  I will need to rewrite the code of Settings class completely.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't answer my question - Do you have an *actual, practical* problem here? If you are just asking why `NSLog` cannot see the change in `@State`, the answer is that that's just how `@State` works.

Comment: Yes the actual problem is that the view is not getting updated.

Comment: I think the problem is I have an Array and each element confirms to `Identifiable` and `Equitable` through `UUID`. So even though element of array is being altered(in this case, the name of preset is getting changed), SwiftUI may be seeing as no change in the array as the element UUIDs it held before are the same which prevents view update.

Comment: I checked with `Dispatchqueue.asyncAfter`...for some reason the State vars are not updated even after 0.5 seconds.

Comment: You are lying to the runtime with your custom Equatable conformance. Two presets are not the same just because they have the same ID. Can you use the synthesized Equatable conformance instead?

Comment: @jnpdx Well how else do I compare two presets? In my app, you can have two presets having exactly same properties.

Comment: Equatable should mean that _all_ properties (ID and otherwise) are the same. Otherwise, SwiftUI's render loop won't know to redraw the View.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the `presentName` getter anywhere inside `body` you'll need to use it in a capture list like this:

```
.onSubmit { [presentName] in
```

This is so that it will create a new closure every time the `presentName` changes, now it will have the latest value.

`body` is only called after a `@State` is set if the getter was used.

Comment: As @Sweeper said, it takes time for State vars setters to get called. I think the main problem here is that the View is not getting updated on change of these State vars.

Comment: `body` is only called if the state getter was called

Comment: Is it setter or getter?

Comment: as i said, the getter

Comment: You mean I am supposed to call the getter for State property to fire the view update?

Comment: no i mean you need to use the getter so that when you use the setter it will update. If you don't use the getter then when you use the setter it will not update.

Comment: Ofcourse I use getter such as in ForEach loop

Comment: I mean the presentName getter

Comment: That is superweird

Comment: It doesn't work no matter what I do. The textField onSubmit doesn't trigger updates to State var. This is the issue.

Comment: did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work. See edits to question.

Comment: Remove `Equatable` and the `==`, it's a very bad idea to do equality based on id